# Rest API - Handle Special Characters in XML Request

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

So I have exposed a `Rest API` where the Request Payload will be in `application/xml`.

**Sample Payload:**

```
<NAMES>
  <NAME ID="P2" DESCRIPTION="Johnson & Johnsons" />
</NAMES>
```

**Code:**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/UpdateSomeThings", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public ResponseEntity<SomeResponseModel> UpdateSomeThings(
        @PathVariable("mId") String mId, @Valid @RequestBody SomeMapModel reqBody) {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Model Classes:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "NAMES")
@Data
public class SomeMapModel {

    @XmlElement(name = "NAME")
    private ChildModel[] chld;

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "NAME")
@Data
public class ChildModel {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String desc;
}
```

**I am getting following error:**

> "status": 400, "error": "Bad Request", "exception":
>   "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
>   "message": "Could not unmarshal to [SomeMapModel]null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException\n - with linked exception:\n[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 41; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.]"

Why can't java parse XML field with '&' in it? How can I handle this in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't java parse XML field with '&' in it?

Because it's like every other technologies. An XML document is not allowed to contain any & character that is neither part of a char ref like `&lt;` nor escaped. Such a document *has to* be rejected, as a part of XML convention and because there is no rational argument to not reject them. (In case you wonder, that's because the XML provider knows they're doing XML and therefore it shouldn't even be possible for them to create such a broken XML document to provide, let alone insist on it being acceptable once pointed out it is not.)

> How can I handle this in real time?

You're already handling it in the only acceptable way: by refusing the input and responding with an HTTP 400 error, bad request. Let the request sender fix their requests.

For your information, the request should have been:

```
<NAMES>
  <NAME ID="P2" DESCRIPTION="Johnson &amp; Johnsons" />
</NAMES>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution would be to use **org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils** **[HERE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.7)**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/UpdateSomeThings", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public ResponseEntity<String> UpdateSomeThings(
        @PathVariable("mId") String mId, @Valid @RequestBody SomeMapModel reqBody) {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    return new ResponseEntity<>(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(response), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It provides utility method to escape special characters in XML and replace them with Unicode values.

Comment: escaping should be at unmarshalling right? anyhow I am returning a custom response where I will not be sending special characters.

Comment: In your mapping `public ResponseEntity<String> UpdateSomeThings` what is ResponseEntity carrying here ? Is it marshalled response object ?

Comment: I have created response model which will return JSON with error or success message.